# How to properly setup background postgres notify listener with aiopg in aiohttp framework?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I use aiohttp for handle websockets and postgresql listen/notify, with aiopg driver as transport queue between servers.
Part of my server setup:

```
def init(loop):
    ...
    app = Application(loop=loop)
    app.on_startup.append(connect_db)
    app.on_startup.append(start_background_tasks)
    app.on_cleanup.append(cleanup_background_tasks)
    return app


def create_app(loop):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app = init(loop)
    return app
```

Here the my signals:

```
dsn = 'dbname=test user=root password=test host=127.0.0.1'

async def connect_db(app):
    app['db'] = await aiopg.connect(dsn)
    return app

async def listen_events_from_db(app):
    cursos = await app['db'].cursor()
    await cursos.execute("LISTEN test")
    try:
        while True:
            msg = await app['db'].notifies.get()
            # Here will be a coroutine which will send msg to connected websockets
            print('msg: ', msg.payload)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass
    finally:
        app['db'].close()

async def start_background_tasks(app):
    app['psql_listener'] = app.loop.create_task(listen_events_from_db(app))


async def cleanup_background_tasks(app):
    app['psql_listener'].cancel()
    await app['psql_listener']
```

According to docs I wrap background task to try/except and close the task in `on_cleanup` signal. But in that case server fails start with this exception:

> ```
> ...
> raise CancelledError
> concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
> ```

If I delete `on_shutdown` signal and catch a `RuntimeError` then all works fine, except one warning after shutdown about destroing `listen_events_from_db()` which still pending. I guess it is because of while loop.
Here the fixed task:

```
async def listen_events_from_db(app):
    cursos = await app['db'].cursor()
    await cursos.execute("LISTEN test")
    try:
        while True:
            msg = await app['db'].notifies.get()
            print('msg: ', msg.payload)
    except RuntimeError:
        pass
    finally:
        app['db'].close()
```

I'm new in asyncio and aiohttp framework and have feeling that I'm doing it wrong. Please point me to right direction.